# XML Parsing in Databricks Spark Scala AWS using MAVEN - HL7 V3 files from DailyMed

Tags: java, xml, scala, maven, apache-spark

Pulling human prescription label files from [DailyMed - Download all Drug Labels](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/spl-resources-all-drug-labels.cfm). The .xml format that these files come in are HL7 V3 formatted which has proven difficult to parse [See Install Instructions for MAVEN XML Parsing in AWS Clusters in Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/workspace-libraries.html#maven-libraries) despite having the correct libraries installed on my cluster. Any tips or examples of someone parsing these file types correctly from .xml format to a spark dataframe?

My current approach has included retrieving all files and storing them in dbfs.

```
%scala
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("https://dailymed-data.nlm.nih.gov/public-release-files/dm_spl_release_human_rx_part1.zip"), new File("/dbfs/FileStore/your_path_here/dm_spl_release_human_rx_part1.zip"))
```

unzipping the downloaded files

```
%sh
unzip -vu '/dbfs/FileStore/your_path_here/dm_spl_release_human_rx_part1.zip'  -d /dbfs/FileStore/your_path_here/
```

unzipping the zip files inside the unzipped files (inception)

```
%sh
for file in /dbfs/FileStore/your_path_here/prescription/*.zip
do 
unzip -j $file '*.xml' -d /dbfs/FileStore/your_path_here/xml/
done
```

then parsing from here on out becomes difficult because of the unique format of the .xml HL7 V3 format. Toying around converting to .json but ran into special character issues. Now resorting to removing the special characters and continuing to parse as an .xml to a spark dataframe. Any tips on how someone might do this in Spark Scala would be great!

This is an update on an attempted read and the resulting message.

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml.schema_of_xml
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.read.format("xml").load("/FileStore/your_path_here/xml/ABD6ECF0-DC8E-41DE-89F2-1E36ED9D6535.xml")
// val payloadSchema = schema_of_xml(df.select("payload").as[String])
// val parsed = df.withColumn("parsed", from_xml($"payload", payloadSchema))

df.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnOJ.png)

Comment: Hi Clay! Welcome :) Can you include any `spark.read` commands you have tried? Including any (error) output? Please do so by editing your Question.

Comment: Hi @tjheslin1 - there isn't really a clear error. The data frame looks to be empty. I included a screenshot in the post above.

Having attempted to parse the .xml into a .json file, we achieved 90% progress towards our goal until we bumped up against one of the  required nested structured fields becoming an array of strings due to what we were guessing was a duplicated key since that is a typical problem when changing file formats in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had a developer on my team (https://github.com/gardnmi) which helped out in parsing the .xml documents, eventually passing them to a dataframe. He did a great job! Putting this out here in hopes that someone else might be able to use it/contribute to it.

```
%python 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xml.dom import minidom
import pathlib
import os
import fnmatch
import lxml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict

directory = '/dbfs/FileStore/your_path/your@domain.com/label/xml/'
files = pathlib.Path(f'{directory}').glob('*.xml')
rows = []
unscanned_files = []

for n, file in enumerate(files):
  if file.name == 'ABD6ECF0-DC8E-41DE-89F2-1E36ED9D6535_without_character_or_first_two_lines.xml':
    pass
  print(f'{n}: {file.name}')

  doc = minidom.parse(str(file))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.toxml(), 'lxml')
  set_id = soup.find('setid')['root']
  text = defaultdict(list)
  
  indication_code = soup.find('code', attrs={'code': '34067-9'}) # Indication and Usage Heading
  unclassified_code = soup.find('code', attrs={'code': '42229-5'}) # Unclassified Heading
  
  # File may not contain Indication and Usage Heading
  if indication_code:
    for sibling in indication_code.nextSiblingGenerator():
      if sibling.name and sibling.text:
        if sibling.name != 'component':
          paragraphs = sibling.find_all('paragraph')
          if paragraphs:
            for paragraph in paragraphs:
              text['34067-9'].append(paragraph.text.strip('\n').replace("\n", ""))            
              # Some Text is contained within lists.  See file 002bf3fe-96c9-4969-b5f8-8818a98be6b2.xml
              for sibling in paragraph.nextSiblingGenerator():
                if sibling.name and sibling.text:
                  lists = sibling.find_all('item')
                  if lists:
                    for list_tag in lists:
                      text['34067-9'].append(list_tag.text.strip('\n').replace("\n", ""))
                         
        else:
          unclassified_code = sibling.find('code', attrs={'code': '42229-5'}) # Code 42229-5 is used for Structured Product Labeling Unclassified Section   
          if unclassified_code:
            for sibling in unclassified_code.nextSiblingGenerator():
              if sibling.name and sibling.text:
                paragraphs = sibling.find_all('paragraph')
                if paragraphs:
                  for paragraph in paragraphs:
                    text['42229-5'].append(paragraph.text.strip('\n').replace("\n", ""))                   
                    # Some Text is contained within lists.  See file 002bf3fe-96c9-4969-b5f8-8818a98be6b2.xml
                    for sibling in paragraph.nextSiblingGenerator():
                      if sibling.name and sibling.text:
                        lists = sibling.find_all('item')
                        if lists:
                          for list_tag in lists:
                            text['42229-5'].append(list_tag.text.strip('\n').replace("\n", ""))
                    
                    
  # Runs if no Indication and Usage Section Found.
  # Indications and Usage may be under the unclassified heading
  elif unclassified_code:
    for sibling in unclassified_code.nextSiblingGenerator():
      if sibling.name and sibling.text:
        paragraphs = sibling.find_all('paragraph')
        if paragraphs:
          for paragraph in paragraphs:
            text['42229-5'].append(paragraph.text.strip('\n').replace("\n", ""))        
            # Some Text is contained within lists.  See file 002bf3fe-96c9-4969-b5f8-8818a98be6b2.xml
            for sibling in paragraph.nextSiblingGenerator():
              if sibling.name and sibling.text:
                lists = sibling.find_all('item')
                if lists:
                  for list_tag in lists:
                    text['42229-5'].append(list_tag.text.strip('\n').replace("\n", ""))            

  
  # If no loic heading is found return none
  else:
    text[None].append(None)
    unscanned_files.append(file.name)
    
  for k,v in text.items():
    for n,l in enumerate(v):
      rows.append((
        file.name, # xml file
        set_id, # drug id
        k,# code https://www.fda.gov/industry/structured-product-labeling-resources/section-headings-loinc 
        n+1,# number of text found 
        l # text
      ))
      
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['file_name', 'set_id', 'loinc', 'loinc_count_per_file', 'loinc_paragraph_text'])
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sandbox.humanPrescriptionLabel_xml")
sdf.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('sandbox.humanPrescriptionLabel_xml')
```